# visualise lookup field

Tags: sharepoint-designer

When I visualise an lookup field it seem like this :

[image]

this the code in SharePoint designer :

```
<tr>
                    <td width="190px" valign="top" class="ms-formlabel">
                        <H3 class="ms-standardheader">
                            <nobr>Référence</nobr>
                        </H3>
                    </td>
                    <td width="400px" valign="top" class="ms-formbody">
                        <xsl:value-of select="@R_x00e9_f_x00e9_rence_x0020_cour"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
```

any ideas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just add this  :disable-output-escaping="yes" to xsl:value-of:

```
<xsl:value-of select="@R_x00e9_f_x00e9_rence_x0020_cour" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try stripping the HTML from the value:

```
<xsl:variable name="StripHTML"><![CDATA[<\s*\w.*?>|<\s*/\s*\w\s*.*?>]]></xsl:variable> 
<xsl:analyze-string select="@ows_Body" regex="{$StripHTML}">
  <xsl:non-matching-substring>
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </xsl:non-matching-substring>
</xsl:analyze-string>
```

http://appdevonsharepoint.com/using-xslt-2-0-to-remove-html-tags-from-a-value/

Comment: do you know haw to do it with xslt version 1?